# SQL Server Taking data to one row from next row

Tags: sql-server, row, sql-server-2014, intervals, copying

I have the table:

```
| IntervalID | From |
| ---------- | ---- |
|          1 |    1 |
|          2 |   10 |
|          3 |   20 |
|          4 |   30 |
|          5 |   40 |
```

These table defines me intervals. First would be [1,10], second -[10,20].
I would like to have the table of these intervals. It would look like this:

```
| IntervalID | From | To |
| ---------- | ---- | -- |
|          1 |    1 | 10 |
|          2 |   10 | 20 |
|          3 |   20 | 30 |
|          4 |   30 | 40 |
|          5 |   40 | 50 |
```

How can I do this? The thing is that in column TO the value has to be taken from next row in column From.

Comment: What version of `SQLServer` are you using? The answer depends heavily on this. You could either use [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) or a correlated subquery.

Comment: Then you're lucky, take a look at [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx).

Comment: Really would like to be lucky, but my SQL Server can't see this function. Doesn't LEAD work for 2012 version?

Comment: It's for 2012 and up, so it should work. Can you post the code you are trying?

Comment: LEAD(FROM) OVER (ORDER BY FROM) AS TO.               
               The error msg - 'LEAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Ah, that could be related to the Compatibility Level. You could try `ALTER DATABASE yourDBName
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110`, or first check what it is set to